# Ошибка 0xc02020ff при импорте данных из MariaDB в MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb

Возникла у меня небольшая задача перетащить данные из базы mariadb 5.5 в MS SQL 2014.

Поставил нужный ODBC драйвер (почему-то на win10 нужно ставить не x64 версию, а x32), не без бубна, но настроил ODBC Source. Собственно, осталось-то ничего: выбрать откуда и куда перелить данные, да подождать, пока полмиллиона записей зальётся.

Однако, в процессе возникла ошибка:

> - Setting Source Connection (Error) Messages Error 0xc02020ff: Source - field_name [1]: The Source - field_name was unable to retrieve column information for the SQL command. The following error occurred:
>     ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.5.57-MariaDB]You
>     have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>     your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>     '"field_name"' at line 1  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>     Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC02020FF from a
>     method call. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

Как исправить?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33145161/5752652

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл ответ в вопросе [Data Transfer from MySql to SQL server using SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33145161/5752652):

- Открыть настройки ODBC
- Нажать на кнопку Details
- Выбрать закладку Connection
- В поле Initial Statement вписать: `set session sql_mode=ansi_quotes;`

[image: ODBC params]